# Image Augmentation using Keras in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, keras

How do I apply Keras Image Augmentation for multiple images stored in a folder ?

P.S: I tried the below code for a single image and it worked fine.

Could someone help me to solve for multiple images ??

```
enter code here

from keras.preprocessing import image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rotation_range = 30, 
            width_shift_range = 0.2,
            height_shift_range = 0.2, 
            shear_range = 0.2, 
            zoom_range = 0.2,
            horizontal_flip = 0.2,
            fill_mode = "nearest")

for img in glob.glob("Images/*/*.jpg"):
    cv_img = cv2.imread(img)
    cv_resize = cv2.resize(cv_img,(200,200))
    cv_norm_img = cv_resize/255.0
    break


cv_norm_img = np.array(cv_norm_img)

input_batch = cv_norm_img.reshape((1,*cv_norm_img.shape))

i = 0

for output_batch in datagen.flow(input_batch,batch_size=1):
    plt.figure()
    imgplot = plt.imshow(image.img_to_array(output_batch[0]))
    i+=1
    if i==10:
        break
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use ImageDataGenerator.flow from directory. Documentation is 
at https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/. images will be an array of shape (batch_size, 200, 200, 3)
Note: each time you run this it will put batch_size more images in the 
save_to_dir so you may not want to include that parameter.
You can access the individual images as img1=images[0], img2=images[1] etc
Set up your generator as follows

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 30, width_shift_range = 0.2,
                             height_shift_range = 0.2,
                             shear_range = 0.2, 
                             zoom_range = 0.2,
                             rescale=1/255,
                             horizontal_flip = True,
                             fill_mode = "nearest")
data=datagen.flow_from_directory(your_dir, target_size=(200, 200),
                                 batch_size=your_file_count, shuffle=False,
                                 save_to_dir=your_save_dir,save_format='png',
                                 interpolation='nearest')
images,labels=data.next()
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! That worked! It returned the exact image count(1000 images) with 25 classes in my Images directory.
I did not include the save_to_dir parameter to save the new images which will be created.
So instead of trying to save them, how could I print my batch_size images for each original image(1000 original images) from my Images directory  ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Print images?

Comment: Sorry I mean view / access the augmented images.

Comment: you can iterate through the images in a for loop images[i] and use matplotlib to display them.